Is it OK to post a question about an Sage Advice Column entry?
I find myself repeatedly referring to the Sage Advice Compendium (SAC) entry that defines what counts as magical; however, there is no way (that I know of) to directly point at that entry, the best I could find is pointing at the page in the SAC. Or I have been pointing at other questions that ask if something is magical, and have a decent answer discussing the SAC entry that I can refer to.
I've been thinking about posting a self-answer question that asks, "When is something magical in 5e", and essentially answers by explaining what the core rules say (little), and briefly what the SAC is, and finally reproducing that SAC entry, maybe with some added commentary.
As I had some negative reactions in the past with asking questions that I think would be useful to have in answering questions, I thought I check in here first to see what the community thinks about adding the question. If the answer is no, that should not be done, I also would be grateful if someone has a better way to refer to that specific entry.

This question already exists.
See here: How do I know if an ability is magical?

Often confusion arises when the Antimagic Field spell is used, an Armor of Invulnerability is worn, or the Beholder's anti-magic ray is employed, whether a given character's ability will still function.
The spell does give you some guidelines on how to adjudicate the effects of the loss of magic but says very little about how to determine what is affected.
In short, how do I tell if an ability is magical?

And of course, both answers provided quote the SAC entry you’re referring to. If you have a new answer, you can post it, but be sure it contributes something novel to the discussion. And while I’m generally against posting dupes for the sake of posting dupes, you can refer to Someone_Evil’s guidance on the issue here: Is creating duplicate signpost questions wrong?.
Additionally, you can also just link directly to the entry on D&D Beyond.

Thanks, both of these look like good proxies.
